# Efficiently load 5 larger than fullscreen Bitmaps into my Android Live Wallpaper and scroll them parralax

Tags: android, bitmap, wallpaper, parallax, bitmapfactory

So I'm new to Java and this kind of coding.

I'm trying to make a Parrallax scrolling Live Wallpaper. But I'm having memory issues.

Well I have made it, and it works on on the phone I have. But I think the way i have done it is not very efficient at all. Because when I try it on other phones it doesn't work. It breaks at my Out Of Memory catcher. I added another layer and now it does the same thing on my phone too. So I am able to debug it. Basically I guess I'm using up-to or over 16 meg of memory.

If someone could take a look at my code and help me load in the bitmaps more efficiently that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how I'm currently doing it:

```
static class Layer {
    public Bitmap bitmap;
    private float scale = 1.0f;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    public Layer(Bitmap b) {
        this.bitmap = b;
    }
    public void setScale(float factor) {
        scale = factor;
    }
    public Matrix getMatrix(float x, float y) {
        if (scale == 1) {
            matrix.reset();
        } else {
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        }
        matrix.postTranslate(x, y);
        return matrix;
    }
}

public static List<Integer> findLayers(Integer path) {

    List<Integer> files = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    files.add(R.drawable.planet_layer4);
    files.add(R.drawable.planet_layer3);
    files.add(R.drawable.planet_layer2);
    files.add(R.drawable.planet_layer1);    
    files.add(R.drawable.planet_layer0);

    return files;
}   



    private void loadLayers() {
        try {
            clearLayers();
            for (Integer file: layerFiles) {
                addLayer(file);
            }
            recalibrateLayers();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            layers.clear();
            Toast.makeText(LiveWallpaper.this, "There was a problem loading the wallpaper. Please contact the developer.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
            layers.clear();
            Toast.makeText(LiveWallpaper.this, "Whoops, we ran out of memory trying to load the images. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void addLayer(int name) throws IOException {
        Bitmap layer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), name);
        if (layer == null) {
            throw new IOException("BitmapFactory couldn't decode asset " + name);
        }
        synchronized(layers) {
            layers.add(new Layer(layer));
        }
    }

    private void clearLayers() {
        synchronized(layers) {
            layers.clear();
        }
    }

    private void recalibrateLayers() {
        for (Layer layer : layers) {
            final int bitmapHeight = layer.bitmap.getHeight();
            layer.setScale((float)mHeight / (float)bitmapHeight);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawParallax);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);

        mHeight = height;

        recalibrateLayers();

        drawBackgrounds();

    }
```

And here is where I draw them.

```
/*
     * Draw one frame of the animation. This method gets called repeatedly
     * by posting a delayed Runnable. You can do any drawing you want in
     * here.
     */
    void drawBackgrounds() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        final Rect frame = holder.getSurfaceFrame();

        mFrame = frame;

        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) {
                // draw something
                drawParallax(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }


    }

    void drawParallax(Canvas c) {
        int frameWidth = mFrame.width();

        for (int i=layers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Layer layer = layers.get(i);
            Bitmap bitmap = layer.bitmap;
            float bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth() * layer.scale;
            float max = frameWidth - bitmapWidth;
            float offset = mOffset * max;

            final Matrix m = layer.getMatrix(offset, 0);

            c.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, null);
        }


    }
```

Comment: you can read about here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html and more details here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html